# Apple Invitation Process has changed Unable to Access provisioning profile in developer.apple.com

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently i got invitation from my Team as "Admin" , When i logged in i received below message
[image]

then when i see my membership it is showing Admin only but still I'm unable to access my Certificates. So please can any body suggest me with appropriate role to access my certificates. and i checked my colleagues membership with Admin but he can able to access his certificates. Please refer below image FYI Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: How is this problem related to the Swift or Objective-C programming languages?

Comment: I wonder if this problem is related to the very recent (like within the past day or two) "teams and roles have been unified" migration in the Apple Developer Program?

Comment: @MartinR may be not related to programming language , Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific well-defined categories. so i hope Swift  or objective c programmers can able to Answer this or face this issue so mentioned , what's  wrong with this? anyways some body removed that Tags and Thanks for your time and advise next time i will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue today. I had received an invite and when I clicked on it, I got the same response as invitation process has changed.

[image: Previous Invitation]

Previously you were invited through the developer program as you can see in the screenshot above.

Now you simply need to ask your team to invite you through [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) and then you need to accept that invitation which will look like image below.

[image: New Invitation]

Comment: Okay, but in App store connect my id already there so, how can they send another invitation. Before the rules are different now it seems different so my team asking me what is purpose to send another invitation.

Comment: @Bittoo, you need to be added to the relevant role through "users and access" in app store connect. Then you will get an invite, which is basically the 2nd image in my answer.